# ElasticSearch Date Range for future date

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range

I am trying to create a query that will give me accounts that was created before a certain future date. I would like delete those account that were created 30 days before that future date. I am not sure how to write that range. Currently I have a query that gives me account that was created 30 days before today.

```
            range: {
                updatedAt: {
                  lte: "now-2592000/s",
                },
              },
```

Some guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what format date? Could give example of document?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [_delete_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)

```
POST <index-name>/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "createdAt": {
        "lte": "2022-10-31||-30d" --> any future date
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pass any date  with "||" at end.

My createdAt field is indexed using  type "date"

Comment: He do not want to delete account created in last 30 days. Instead he has some future date. And want to delete all account 30 days less than that future that.

Comment: @AmanMehta I have corrected the code